# php string comparison based on wildcard

Tags: php, string, wildcard, string-comparison

need to compare two strings to get a PAIR with only condition that only character at 5th index is different (ignoring the first 4 characters)... in mysql it can be achieved by INBXOLC800Y = INBX_LC800Y (using the '_' wildcard) but how to do this in PHP... here is my code uptill now but i guess there might be a more smarter and/or shortest way ???

```
$first_sku_full=  "INBXOLC800Y";
$first_sku_short= substr($first_sku_full, 5); // gives LC800Y

$second_sku_full= "INBXPLC800Y";
$second_sku_short= substr($second_sku_full, 5); // gives LC800Y

if ( $first_sku_short == $second_sku_short ) {
    // 6th character onward is matched now included 5th character  
    $first_sku_short= substr($first_sku_full, 4); 
    $second_sku_short= substr($second_sku_full, 4); 
    if ( $first_sku_short != $second_sku_short ) { 
        echo "first and second sku is a pair";     
    }else{
        echo "first and second sku is NOT a pair;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You're never checking the first 4 characters.

Comment: @Barmar yes, i forget to add that first 4 characters do not required to be checked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten it by not assigning all those variables, just test the substrings in the `if`.

```
if (substr($first_sku_full, 5) == substr($second_sku_full, 5)) {
    if ($first_sku_full[4] != $second_sku_full[4])
        echo "first and second sku are a pair";
    } else {
        echo "first and second sku are NOT a pair";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We use `AND` to eliminate further `if..else`

```
$first_sku_full=  "INBXOLC800Y";
$first_sku_short= substr($first_sku_full, 5); // gives LC800Y

$second_sku_full= "INBXPLC800Y";
$second_sku_short= substr($second_sku_full, 5); // gives LC800Y

if ($first_sku_short == $second_sku_short && $first_sku_full[4] != $second_sku_full[4]) {
    echo "first and second sku are a pair";
} else {
    echo "first and second sku are NOT a pair";
}
```